# ¿Como hacer una relación uno a muchos correctamente en laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tenia una web en laravel que habia dejado a medias un año atras, esta funcionaba perfectamente hasta que intento hacer una consulta uno a muchos con eloquent y una clave primaria de tipo string. me sale el error
**Trying to get property of non-object**

En la linea de mi plantilla blade que possee {{$post->category->url}}

He intentado de todo lo mas raro es que con el atributo imagen si funciona (en mi plantilla tambien hay un $post->image->name) claro que el de imagen es una relacion uno a muchos pero con una clave primaria numérica.Tambien se me hace extraño que al intentar acceder a la categoria($post->category) me devuelve un string

Este es el codigo de las migraciones

```
class AddUrlCategory extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('url',100)->unique();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
            $table->dropColumn('url');
        });
    }
}

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title',100)->unique();
            $table->string('url',100)->unique();
            $table->bigInteger('image_id');
            $table->string('category',20);
            $table->text('description');
            $table->bigInteger('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
}
```

Este es el codigo de los modelos

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'category','url'
    ];//creo que estoes para cambios simultaneos y tambien para hacer cambios con tinger

    function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post','category','category');
    }
    function images(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Image','category','category');
    }
    protected $table = 'categories';

    protected $primaryKey = 'category';
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    public $incrementing = false;
}

class Post extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'description','url','image_id','category', 'user_id',
    ];//creo que estoes para cambios simultaneos y tambien para hacer cambios con tinger

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category','category','category');
    }

    public function image()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Image');
    }
}
```

Metodo controlador de la vista que genera el porblema

```
public function index()
{
    define('head',array('title'=>"Blog de softweb",
    'description'=>"Bienvenido al blog de softweb" )); 
    
    $posts=\App\Post::paginate(6);
    $categories=\App\Category::all();


    return view('posts',['categories'=>$categories,'posts'=>$posts,'currentCategory'=>null]);
}
```

Comment: Ocupamos tu consulta

Comment: te refieres a mi controlador

Comment: A tu consulta de dónde tratas de obtener los modelos de post

Comment: Ya lo acabo de solucionar disculpa la molestia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré el fallo y es que cuando se hace una relacion entre tablas los nombres de los atributos deben de ser distintos a los nombres de las relaciones (los metodos que usamos en los modelos para acceder a la tabla relacionada)

citando un poco a la documentación de laravel

> Los nombres de las relaciones no pueden colisionar con los nombres de
> los atributos, ya que eso podría llevar a que su modelo no sepa cuál
> resolver.

Por ejemplo en mi caso

```
 public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category','category','category');
    }
```

deberia ser

```
 public function categoria()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category','category','category');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu  fallo empieza aquí:

```
$posts=\App\Post::paginate(6);
```

Pues si quieres obtener los posts y su categoría, está consulta no lo hará pues solo devuelve los modelos de posts (*con una propiedad `category`* que servirá como vínculo).

- Salvo que dentro de la vista iteres tanto a posts y categories y **evalúes si la llave foránea de cada post se corresponde con la llave primaria de cada categoría**, pero ¿para qué llevar esa lógica y complicación a la vista?

Tampoco hace mucho sentido esto:

```
$post->category->url
```

Pues tú consulta anterior no trae ningún objeto o colección  que nos de acceso a las categorías y en consecuencia es lógico el fallo pues quieres la propiedad **`URL`** de algo que es **`null`**

Lo más simple en estos casos es que cargues las relaciones desde la consulta a través del concepto de *eager loading*:

```
$posts = Post::with('category')->paginate(6);
```

De está forma al iterar si podrás (*por qué existe*) acceder a los valores de cada categoría asociada debido a que la consulta trae en un objeto dentro de post su respectiva categoría.

**Fuentes  de consulta**

- [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: Me pareció super interesante tu respuesta Gracias , sin embargo, post posee una clave que lo relaciona con las categorias. por lo que si puedo acceder a la url el fallo estaba era que creo que los atributos y las relaciones osea el metodo que uso para hacer la consulta de uno amuchos deben de tener distinto nombre lo cual en mi caso no pasaba

Comment: Claro que posts posee una clave que es la foránea, pero por si sola solo da un número y nadamas, necesitas un join o subconsulta para componer la salida que quieres, al margen de tu respuesta, estás observaciones que te hago más el hecho de que tus consultas no están bien hechas son puntos importantes

Comment: De nuevo gracias, lo que pasa es que en la vista que utilizo uso todas las categorías y todos los post, aparte de el inert join que pido en la pregunta, se que esas consultas solo me traen todos los post y todas las consultas, pero debido a las particularidades que nos ofrece laravel puedo generar  un resultado similar a un join usando eloquent y los metodos para relaciones. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships